# Use of std::string giving undefined template error

Tags: android, c++, c++11

I am building Android O for my device and this is one of the error in C++ code that is a shim in the source for my device,

```
device/leeco/x3/libs/libmtk_symbols/mtk_ui.cpp:40:21: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'
        std::string my_requestorName("<Unknown>");
                    ^
external/libcxx/include/iosfwd:193:32: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_string;
                               ^
```

Now, I am not sure how to solve this, I tried to change it to simple 'string' from 'std::string' and it didn't work.
I am not very good at C++, so i am not sure what the possible solution here is.
It worked fine enough in N, but in O, its giving this error.
I am building LineageOS 15.0, it was fine in LineageOS 14.1.

EDIT:
Ok, I fixed it by including iostream
I dont know why it was not needed in N anyways.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` before using it?

Comment: Yes, didnt help